# Hapi.js Keep Service Running After Handler Returns

Tags: node.js, response, hapi.js

The new version of Hapi.js uses `async (request, h) => { return "result"; }` instead of the old `(request, reply) => { reply("result"); }` pattern of route handler. I get a lot of convenience with `async` handler function.

However, if I want some process keep running after sending response, what should do?

Eidt 1: I decide to run the process and return result asynchronously. Hope there is a more proper way.

Answer (score -1):

You can always return a promise from your handler.

This code will wait 10 seconds before resolve the promise. (Promise.delay() is [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) promise method.)

```
handler: async (request, h) => {
    return Promise.try(() => {
        return Promise.delay(10000)
    }).then(() => {
        return "10 seconds passed"
    })
}
```

Comment: This probably is not what I am looking for. My goal is running some process **after** async function returns. In my opinion this function runs a process **before** the return.